# How to implement scale-9 (9-slice) for custom background art created for UIButton

Tags: ios, uikit

What do I need to do programatically in order to use the same background image for UIButton of variable size? (commonly known as 9-slice scaling or scale-9)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check out:

```
- (UIImage *)stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:(NSInteger)leftCapWidth topCapHeight:(NSInteger)topCapHeight
```

In the UIImage class.

If I understand what you're looking for correctly, this while allow you to use one png to define how your button looks, and it will stretch to any size vertically or horizontally.

Comment: Good answer from 2009, but as Evan said, `resizableImageWithCapInsets` is now the more up-to-date API

Answer (score 16):

I know this is an old thread, but to anyone who stumbles upon this after iOS 5 is released, it should be noted from Apple's documentation that the **stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:topCapHeight:** method is deprecated as of iOS 5:

[Deprecated UIImage Methods](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIImage_Class/DeprecationAppendix/AppendixADeprecatedAPI.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006890-CH3-SW4)

> Deprecated in iOS 5.0. Deprecated. Use the **resizableImageWithCapInsets**: instead, specifying cap insets such that the interior is a 1x1 area.

So now that iOS 6 has been announced and will be here soon, anyone developing for iOS 5 and higher should probably take a look at **resizableImageWithCapInsets** instead, which documentation can be found here:

[UIImage Class Reference - resizableImageWithCapInsets](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIImage_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIImage/resizableImageWithCapInsets:)

Just thought I'd mention it to help any developers who needed an updated answer to this problem.