# Update super view size on setting of UIButton image?

Tags: ios, uibutton, uiimage, constraints, bounding-box

My button has constraints. For example: `(4, 4, 4, 12)`.

I want to set its image (image and button sizes are the same) and change its size to a fixed bounding rect. For example: `CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 200)`. So image should be scalled proportionally but be less than this rect. And of course I should change button size and the size of the view which contains this button.

How to solve this issue? I know how to do it without constraints only and it is enough simple but my project requires them.

Comment: Your question is not clear. You say that button and image are the same size and then you say change "it's size" what is "it's"? Why don't you just set the Image of the UIButton and only deal with the button?

Comment: try to "simply" set the button image programmatically and look what happens with this button. Currently I try to solve it via another way: I use UIImageView and gesture recognizer to simulate the button

Comment: you mean like using aspect fit? or are you talking about how to implement a [scale-9 button](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1172731/how-to-implement-scale-9-for-custom-background-art-created-for-uibutton)

Answer (score 0):

Try to set the Image property of the button.

```
UIImage *btnImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"];
[btnTwo setImage:btnImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Then you only worry about the button.